# How to plot phase portiere and the solutions of ODES

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

Dear All  I know how to plot phase portrait for  the system of  nonlinear odes

but I did not know whey  the result of `Show` the parametric solutions with phase portiere  not good

I  Wrote the code as following:

```
sol[{N0_, I0_}?NumericQ] := 
  First@NDSolve[{N1'[t] == 
      r N1[t] (1 - \[Beta] N1[t]) - \[Eta] N1[t] I1[t], 
       I1'[t] == \[Sigma] + (\[Rho] N1 [t] I1[t])/(
       m + N1[t]) - \[Delta] I1[t] - \[Mu] N1[t] I1[t], N1[0] == N0, 
     I1[0] == I0}, {N1, I1}, {t, 0, 365}];
P1 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{N1[t], I1[t]} /. sol[#] & /@ Range[0, 2, 0.1]], {t, 0, 
   30}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> Full, 
  Frame -> True, MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

where

```
r = 0.431201; \[Beta] = 2.99 *10^-6;
\[Eta] = 0.2 ; \[Sigma] = 0.7; \[Rho] = 0.003; m = 0.427;  \[Delta] = \
0.57; \[Mu] = .82;
```

and I used `StreamPlot` as following:

```
f[N1_, I1_] = r N1 (1 - \[Beta] N1) - \[Eta] N1 I1;
g[N1_, I1_] = \[Sigma] + (\[Rho] N1 I1)/(
   m + N1) - \[Delta] I1 - \[Mu] N1 I1;
G[{N1_, I1_}] = {f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]};
```

then

```
StreamPlot[{f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]}, {N1, 0, 30}, {I1, 0, 30}, 
 StreamStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AxesLabel -> {"N1", "I1"}]

Show[StreamPlot[{f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]}, {N1, 0, 30}, {I1, 0, 30}, 
  StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  Frame -> True, AxesLabel -> {"N1", "I1"}, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  PlotRange -> All], P1]
```

the finale result was,

[image]

can any one help me to improve my result? it was worked before I submitted the question and got the result above. my aim is plotting solutions of the system with different initial conditions and show the them with phase portrait.

Comment: Hi Sana, your code does not produce the results you posted.  Could you check that they're correct?  A couple problems I see: 1) `?NumericQ` is applied to a list and 2) you call `sol` with only a number not a list in the `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: welcome @chris K  i used the same steps with other system and it worked as well  and get this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = 0.431201; \[Beta] = 2.99*10^-6;
\[Eta] = 0.2; \[Sigma] = 0.7; \[Rho] = 0.003; m = 0.427; \[Delta] = \
0.57; \[Mu] = .82;
n = ParametricNDSolveValue[{N1'[t] == 
     r N1[t] (1 - \[Beta] N1[t]) - \[Eta] N1[t] I1[t], 
    I1'[t] == \[Sigma] + (\[Rho] N1[t] I1[t])/(m + 
         N1[t]) - \[Delta] I1[t] - \[Mu] N1[t] I1[t], N1[0] == N0, 
    I1[0] == I0}, N1, {t, 0, 365}, {N0, I0}];
i = ParametricNDSolveValue[{N1'[t] == 
     r N1[t] (1 - \[Beta] N1[t]) - \[Eta] N1[t] I1[t], 
    I1'[t] == \[Sigma] + (\[Rho] N1[t] I1[t])/(m + 
         N1[t]) - \[Delta] I1[t] - \[Mu] N1[t] I1[t], N1[0] == N0, 
    I1[0] == I0}, I1, {t, 0, 365}, {N0, I0}];
P = Flatten[
   Table[ParametricPlot[{n[x, y][t], i[x, y][t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}, Frame -> True, MaxRecursion -> 8, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> {"N1", "I1"}, 
     PlotStyle -> Blue], {x, 0, 2, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2, .2}]];



f[N1_, I1_] = r N1 (1 - \[Beta] N1) - \[Eta] N1 I1;
g[N1_, I1_] = \[Sigma] + (\[Rho] N1 I1)/(m + 
      N1) - \[Delta] I1 - \[Mu] N1 I1;
G[{N1_, I1_}] = {f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]};


P1 = StreamPlot[{f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]}, {N1, 0, 5}, {I1, 0, 2}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   StreamStyle -> Gray, StreamPoints -> Fine];

Show[P, P1]
```

[image: fig1]

To display the points at different scales use the code

```
point = {{0., 1.2280701754385965}, {1.4649020816028147`, 
    0.4905006385109145}, {334447.8852, 0}};
g1 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.05], Point[point]}, 
  Frame -> False]; P = 
 Flatten[Table[
   ParametricPlot[{n[x, y][t], i[x, y][t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 5}, {0, 2}}, Frame -> True, MaxRecursion -> 8, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> {"N1", "I1"}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue], {x, -1, 2, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2, .2}]]; P1 = 
 StreamPlot[{f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]}, {N1, -1, 5}, {I1, 0, 2}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
  StreamStyle -> Gray, StreamPoints -> Fine]; s1 = Show[P, P1]
P2 = Flatten[
   Table[ParametricPlot[{n[x, y][t], i[x, y][t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
     PlotRange -> {{334446, 334449}, {-1, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
     MaxRecursion -> 8, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> {"N1", "I1"}, 
     PlotStyle -> Blue, Axes -> False], {x, 334446, 334449, 
     0.3}, {y, -1, 2, .2}]];

P3 = StreamPlot[{f[N1, I1], g[N1, I1]}, {N1, 334446, 334449}, {I1, -1,
    2}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
  StreamStyle -> Gray, StreamPoints -> Fine]; s2 = Show[P2, P3]
{Show[s1, g1], Show[s2, g1]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Yes, i aim to get this result, Thankful @Alex Trounev

Comment: I try to add the list of the points on the graph but the result not fine, can you help me                                                                                                                                      ListPlot[{{0.`, 1.2280701754385965`}, {1.4649020816028147` , 
   0.4905006385109145},{334447.8852, 0}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, (PointSize /@ {Small, Medium, Large})}]                                                       I succeed to add the first two points only and add the third point in the separate graph but the result not fine. @Alex Trounev

Comment: The third point can not fit because it does not fall into `PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}`.  What is the need to show this point?

Comment: yah, I want to show the solution is stable around this point, I plot it in the new figure and change the range of plot to include the third point but the size of the point is small how can make it larger @Alex Trouneve

Comment: sorry I do not know how to submit the figure here.

Comment: @sanaalharbi See update to my post.

Comment: Tanks a lot @Alex Trounev

Comment: @sanaalharbi You're welcome!

Comment: sorry, Dr.@Alex Trounev I  failed to apply the code with another system.  can I contact you?

Comment: @sanaalharbi What is your system and what message did you receive?

Comment: I plot the stream plot and parametric solutions and apply your code? the stream plot is fine but the parametric solutions don't follow the stream.  can I submit a new system her as of answer question?    @Alex Trounev

Comment: yes, when I used your code by another system I got these InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.000612245} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation. –@Alex Trounev

Comment: @sanaalharbi  Check version `$Version`. What message did you receive?

Comment: I had this message 11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016) @Alex Trounev

Comment: @sanaalharbi I tested the code on "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)". It works well without messages. Perhaps you have a problem with the installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91308/discussion-between-sana-alharbi-and-alex-trounev).